# Is it possible to change the starting date of all the data shown in the magento dashbaord?

Tags: admin, reports, dashboard

I want to show the information from a particular date not from the start/when i install the magento. Is it possible to modify the dashboard to show all the data (most searched, most viewed, favourite etc) from a particular date ?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/12-hours-range-dashboard.html 
I suggest you to try this extension. They have used 12 hours range, you have to change it to whatever date you are looking for. All the best

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box. You would need to rewrite each dashboard block separately because they have no common code to query the database.

#### Examples:

1. `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Searches_Top` has a method `_prepareCollection()` like all admin grids, where the collection is created but not loaded yet. So you can rewrite the block and override the method to add your own filter like this:

   ```
   protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
       $collection = parent::_prepareCollection();
       $collection->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', [ 'gt' => Varien_Date::formatDate('ENTER START DATE') ]);
       return $collection;
   }
   ```

   Note that this actually filters the queries that have been updated since your start date but does not change the number of searches because this data is not available. You'll need to extend the `CatalogSearch` module to collect more fine grained data.
2. `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Sales` loads the sales collection in `_prepareLayout()`, but it gets created in `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection::calculateSales()`, so you coul rewrite the collection and override the method like this

   ```
   public function calculateSales($isFilter = 0) {
       $collection = parent::calculateSales($isFilter);
       $collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', [ 'gt' => Varien_Date::formatDate('ENTER START DATE') ]);
       return $collection;
   }
   ```